# close the frame after detecting qr code with opencv

Tags: python, sqlite, opencv

I've been working on this project to detect qr-code and make attendance and have the outputs in sql database and so far I've gotten everything to work out,

The Problem is I actually want the frame to close when a single QR code is detected, decoded and all of the above process is completed also The camera works and the frame shows up but it is very slow when detecting the QR code.

What actually happens is after the frame is open it constantly and after it detects a QR code, it actually logs multiple (around 15) instances of a QR being detected after like 2 seconds. Also the frame is still up and I can still detect Images.

The frame closes, only after pressing the waitkey which is 27 or 'Esc'

So I am actually looking for 2 Things:

1. How to close the frame after detecting a QR Code?
2. (additional question) how do I detect only one qr code (whether the frame closes or not). So when I scan the QR code, either the frame closes and I am left with one decoded data OR I scan the QR code and the frame remains open, until I hit 'Esc' and I am left with one decoded data.

here is the full code for reference:

```
import cv2
import os
import csv
import sqlite3
import vobject
from datetime import datetime
import numpy as np  
from pyzbar import pyzbar

path = 'qr-codes'

images = []
classNames = []

lists = os.listdir(path)
for cl in lists:
    curImage = cv2.imread(f'{path}/{cl}')
    images.append(curImage)
    classNames.append(os.path.splitext(cl)[0])


def main():
    camera = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    ret, frame = camera.read()


    while ret:
        ret, frame = camera.read()
        recognizer = parse_vcard(frame)
        win_name = 'Face and QR Detection'

        cv2.imshow(win_name, recognizer)       
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == 27:
            break
    
    camera.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

def parse_vcard(frame):
    barcodes = pyzbar.decode(frame)
    for barcode in barcodes:
        x, y, w, h = barcode.rect
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y),(x+w, y+h), (0, 255, 0), 2)
        mydata = barcode.data.decode('utf-8')
        vcard = vobject.readOne(mydata)
        make_attendence(vcard)
    return frame


def make_attendence(vcard):
    name = str(vcard.contents['n'][0].value)
    # print(type(Employee.name))
    profession = str(vcard.contents['title'][0].value)
    now = datetime.now()
    date = datetime.date(now)
    attendance_time = now.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
    leave_time = '21:00:00'
    connection = sqlite3.connect('employee.db')
    conn = connection.cursor()
    # conn.execute("""CREATE TABLE employees (
    #         name text,
    #         profission text,
    #         date date,
    #         attendance_time time,
    #         leave_time time
    #         )""")
    conn.execute("INSERT INTO employees VALUES \
        (:name, :profession, :date, :attendance_time, :leave_time)", {
            'name': name, 
            'profession': profession,
            'date': date,
            'attendance_time': attendance_time,
            'leave_time': leave_time})
    
    connection.commit()
    connection.close()




if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

do not reconnect to the database for every QR code and every picture you take.

connect once. keep the connection.

the imshow window is a window. a "frame" is commonly the term for one picture/image from a video. you can't "close" a frame.

you can close imshow windows with `destroyAllWindows` or individual imshow windows using `destroyWindow`

use python's "pdb" debugger. use a profiler to investigate the time cost of your code. use `time.perf_counter()` and do the measurements yourself, if you don't find a profiler you like.

Comment: how do I detect only one qr code. So when I scan the QR code, either the windows closes and I am left with one decoded data then restart the connect to open the camera again OR I scan the QR code and the frame remains open, until I hit 'Esc' and I am left with one decoded data.